# Using Zeep[xmlsec] on a lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, soap, lxml, zeep

I'm have been trying to deploy a lambda function that need zeep[xmlsec] to work, But at this moment I couldn't install the xmlsec requirement to I am trying to deploy a lambda that queries a soap resource, which is why it has a dependency on the zeep[xmlsec] library. Until now it has been impossible to do so, because it generates the same error as on Mac. Has any of you deployed a lambda that uses said library that can guide me?

poor using virtual environments to install the libraries and create layers but it didn't work. A solution or help how I can do to display the lambda.

Comment: I deploy a lamnda that uses zeep 4.2.1 and lxml 3.8.0, that works for you ?

Comment: sure, that will be works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to deploy a lambda function with `zeep==4.2.1` and `lxml >= 3.8.0` using [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html).

1. First install aws cli and aws SAM CLI
2. Crate a project with SAM CLI and select AWS Quick Start Templates
   [image]
3. Select a template, for example I use the hello world template and then select the version of python, in my case I select the version 3.9
4. Select Image instead of zip 
   [image]
5. add this to the requirements.txt file

```
requests
zeep==4.2.1
lxml >= 3.8.0
urllib3<2
```

and with `sam build` and `sam deploy --guided` you can deploy the lambda function.
Here is the [link a the github code](https://github.com/pablosalazzar/stackoverflow-answer-4) that I use